# Removing all line breaks row by row between quotation mark in notepad++?

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have text file in which I have to remove all line breaks row by row between quotation mark.

how could I do that using notepad++?

great thxs to all.

for example ,raw text is like:

```
"Acquiror Full
Business Description"
"Acquiror Short
Business Description"
```

desired format:

```
"Acquiror Full Business Description"
"Acquiror Short Business Description"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to handle this:

Open Find& Replace Tab: 
Enter this in Find Box : `^"(.*)\r\n(.*)"$`
Replace with: `"$1 $2"`

Note: Select Search Mode as Regex.

[image: Regex Example]

Comment: thx it solves my problem, but the there are line breaks 3 4 5 6 7. i can adjust by adding \r\n(.*) and $3 or more. if there are more automatic way to generalize regex expression. thx

Comment: You Can Change the Regex to :
^"(.*)[\r\n]*(.*)"$

Comment: Not necessary for the examples in the question, but I would recommend changing the `.*` to be `[^"]*` to allow for unexpected quotes in the strings. Making the expression be `^"([^"]*)\r\n([^"]*)"$`